# How can I implement Admin route in Nextjs 13 App using Next Auth?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

Using Nextjs 13 App Directory and Next Auth. The file tree is in the below. Login/SignUp is working, Protect Route working. Admin Route not working

My Problem is, I can't figure out the problem in admin route. It always redirect me to home directory. I checked my database my user role is **"admin"**. and " Still when I try to go to the "**/alluser**" route it redirect me to the home route.

When I try to console log the user in the **AuthProfileMenu** component I get the "admin" in console. But can't manage to naviagte to my admin routes. I manage to implement the protected and guest route but admin route not working.

Is there any better approach or how can I solve the issue?

**AuthProfileMenu** Component Code (console.log -> "admin" or "user" from database)

```
components
 ┣ AuthProfileMenu
 ┃ ┗ AuthProfileMenu.jsx

"use client";

import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useSession, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export default function AuthProfileMenu() {
  const { data, status } = useSession();

  const isAuth = status === "authenticated";

  console.log(data?.user?.role);

  if (isAuth) {
    return (
      <li>
        <div className="dropdown dropdown-hover dropdown-bottom dropdown-end">
          <label tabIndex={0} className="">
            My Account
          </label>
          <ul
            tabIndex={0}
            className="dropdown-content z-[1] menu p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52"
          >
            <li>
              <Link href="/my-profile">My Profile</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              {/* <Link href="/">Logout</Link> */}
              <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Log Out</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <Link href="/register">Sign Up</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/login">Sign In</Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

My admin route layout code (not working -> always false)

```
 ┣ (admin_route)
 ┃ ┗ layout.js


import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import React from "react";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function AdminLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const user = session?.user | undefined;

  const isAdmin = user?.role === "admin";

  if (!isAdmin) return <h1>Error Occured</h1>;

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

My Protected Route code (working)

```
 ┣ (auth)
 ┃ ┗ layout.js


import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import React from "react";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

import Footer from "@/components/Footer/Footer";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar/Navbar";

export default async function PrivateLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session?.user) redirect("/login");

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my Guest route layout code (working)

```
 ┣ (auth)
 ┃ ┗ layout.js

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import React from "react";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function GuestLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (session) redirect("/");

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Here is my [...nextauth] route.js

```
api
 ┗ auth
 ┃ ┣ users
 ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js
 ┃ ┗ [...nextauth]
 ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js

import startDb from "@/lib/db";
import UserModel from "../../../../models/userModel";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
// import clientPromise from "@/lib/db";

export const authOptions = {
  // adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;

        await startDb();

        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
        
        if (!user) throw new Error("email/password mismatch!");

        const passwordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!passwordMatch) throw new Error("email/password mismatch");

        return {
          id: user._id.toString(),
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
          role: user.role,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    jwt(params) {
      if (params.user?.role) {
        params.token.role = params.user.role;
        params.token.id = params.user.id;
      }
      return params.token;
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user = {
          id: token.id,
          role: token.role,
        };
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};

const authHandler = NextAuth(authOptions);

module.exports = {
  GET: authHandler,
  POST: authHandler,
};
```

This is my basic file tree for better understanding

```
app
 ┣ (admin_route)
 ┃ ┣ alluser
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.jsx
 ┃ ┗ layout.js
 ┣ (auth)
 ┃ ┣ login
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.jsx
 ┃ ┣ register
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.jsx
 ┃ ┗ layout.js
 ┣ (private_route)
 ┃ ┣ my-profile
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.jsx
 ┣ api
 ┃ ┗ auth
 ┃ ┃ ┣ users
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ [...nextauth]
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ route.js
components
 ┣ AuthProfileMenu
 ┃ ┗ AuthProfileMenu.jsx
```